# Tools to test/debug/fix PHP concurrency issues?

Tags: php, concurrency, memcached

I find myself doing some relatively advanced stuff with memcached in PHP. It's becoming a mental struggle to think about and resolve race conditions and concurrency issues caused by the lock-free nature of the cache.

PHP seems pretty poor in tools when it comes to concurrency (threads, anyone?), so I wonder if there are any solutions out there to test/debug this properly.

I don't want to wait until two users request two scripts that will run as parallel processes at the same time and cause a concurrency issue that will leave me scratching my head, or that I might not ever notice until it snowballs into a clusterfsck.

Any magic PHP concurrency wand I should know of?

Answer (score 3):

PHP is not a language designed for multi-threading, and I don't think it ever will be.

If you need mutex functionality, PHP has a [Semaphore](http://us.php.net/sem) functions you can compile in.

Memcache has no mutex capability, but it can be emulated using the [Memcache::add()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.memcache-add.php) method.

If you are using a MySQL database, and are trying to prevent some kind of race condition corruption, you can use the [lock tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) statement, or use [transactions](https://web.archive.org/web/20081219053301/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'm still looking for something in the testing department rather than adding safety nets to the implementation without actually testing it in a real concurrent situation. For example it's cool to be able do semaphores, but what's the point if it can't be tested properly?

Comment: I've started using Memcache:add thanks to your advice and I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 1):

You could try pounding on your code with a load test tool that can make multiple requests at the same time. [Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically for this issue but: [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/)?

Comment: For that particular matter I prefer my current file-based logging system with precise timestamps that can help with determining what was running when.